# How to disable all buttons

Tags: c#, button, expression-blend

I have a method that disables all the butttons on my window.
But i can't seem to get the type of Button to match it to the Resource collection

I'm using Expression Blend 3 with a c# code-behind

```
void DisableButtons()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i>= this.Resources.Count -1; i ++)
        {
            if (this.Resources[i].GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                Button btn = (Button)this.Resources[i];
                btn.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Update**

Thanks for the answers!
Ok The loop is working but my code is incorrect.
`this.Resources`
Does not seem to include my buttons! This could be an **Blend** thing?

So Yeah.
I ended up doing it manually. Cause I'm hasty and there isn't a short easy solution. Thanks for all the input though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible I misunderstood something, but you're trying to find Buttons CONTAINED in your window in the RESOURCES of your window? Because those two things are different things alltogether.
If that is the case, either try setting this.IsEnabled = false (but that disables other things, not just buttons), or traverse the logical tree (or visual tree if silverlight) with LogicalTreeHelper/VisualTreeHelper, although that is a VERY expensive method.
Manual workaround would be to give names to all your buttons, make a list of them in codebehind and iterate that list.

**However** the best would be to create a boolean property called AreButtonsEnabled in your ViewModel (if you're not using MVVM than simply on the control itself - but make it DependencyProperty) and bind all your button's IsEnabled property to them! And then in codebehind simply set that boolean to false ... and magic ensues.

If this is not your case then sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: That is the Case, and yours is an interesting idea. I'll Try That.

Answer (score 5):

```
void DisableButtons()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Resources.Count; i ++)
    {
        var btn = Resources[i] as Button;
        if(btn != null)
        {
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Easy way to implement it is use foreach instruction with LINQ query, but this way need more resuources whan easy for.

```
void DisableButtons()
{
    foreach(var button in Resources.OfType<Button>())
    {
        button.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
if (this.Resources[i].GetType() == typeof(Button)))
```

or even better

```
if (this.Resources[i] is Button))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your loop statement is wrong.  `i>= this.Resources.Count -1` should be `i <= this.Resources.Count - 1;`  It'll never get into your loop.

Also, this is just a style thing, but I'd rewrite it as:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < Resources.Count; i ++)
    {
        Button btn = Resources[i] as Button; // btn will be null if not a Button

        if( btn != null )
        {
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about that?

```
if (this.Resources[i] is Button)
```

That way you can get anything that inherits from Button.

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple method.
First you create a bool.

```
bool enableButtons = true;
```

Now I add a timer to the form which is active all the time.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (enableButtons = false)
 {
     button1.Enabled = false;
     button2.Enabled = false;
 }
 else
 {
     button1.Enabled = true;
     button2.Enabled = true;
 }
}
```

So whenever I want to disable the buttons, I just change `enableButtons` to false.